# Как остановить BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

Нужно остановить BroadcastReceiver или поставить на паузу, но не из активити, а из него самого. Шаблон BroadcastReceiver'а:

```
// какие-то действия
// остановка BroadcastReceiver
```

Comment: уберите `Intent` на отправку сообщения в `Broadcast`

Comment: Broadcast через манифест создан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast()` - но не все можно так останавливать, только те которые [Ordered](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) - то есть те которые обходят по порядку ресиверы. Фактически абортом бродкаста вы прервете цепочку обработчиков.